# Slow connection establishment with SMB on Windows 7 using VPN

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, windows-7, server-message-block, netbios

I am using Windows 7 professional with service pack 1 installed.

After installing large amount of system updates (using Windows Update), I started to experience problems with SMB on my PC. This problem was not present before the update. Taking into account the number of update patches, I am not able to track which one was the cause.

Connection establishment with my network share takes 20 seconds (exactly - look at the wireshark log: time marked in red). From what I can see, there are two tries querying NBNS, each taking exactly 10 seconds. After second attempt (after these 20 seconds), connection is live and I am not experiencing any more lags - this occurs only on initial connection.

Here is a screenshot from wireshark:

[image]

Problem is present **always when I start the connection anew**. The problem is not present while using WIFI/LAN without VPN.

System eventlog is clear. The only thing including SMB there is branchcacheSMB, where all of the values are equal 0.

What are your thoughts on this? Apparently it is not a client problem, since it worked good before the updates. What could cause such behavior?

Thank you for responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved with registry change. I am not totally sure what was changed (I modified multiple entries at once), but after adding/modifying some simple parameters now connection is established immediately (system restart is a must). Few days after the issue was resolved I was not able to track changes in my registry, so I am not able to mark the culprict. But article below might be of use:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and